# Test scenarios for REST services with JSON payload

Tags: json, rest, testing

I am looking for guidelines/best practice for testing REST services.  For example, if I have the following JSON payload in a REST request:

```
{
    "maxActiveBadges": "1",
    "photoUrl": "https://someurl/?employeeId=12345",
    "employeeId": "12345"
}
```

The way I've approached testing this is obviously number 1 to test the happy path scenario to ensure I get a 200 response code.  Then there are many negative scenarios I can cover:

missing input fields, misspelled input fields, incorrect formatting of input fields (e.g. string instead of int), invalid json and exceeding field input lengths.

My question is how extensive should the negative testing be?  Should I reasonably assume that the service will deal with any inputs gracefully, by returning an appropriate error status code and message in the response body?

A secondary question - are there certain characters that the service should never accept e.g. `\?<>` for security reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I reasonably assume that the service will deal with any inputs gracefully, by returning an appropriate error status code and message in the response body?

it depends on which framework you use and what do they write in manual. it also depends on if you set it up correctly and correctly specified all validation rules

> My question is how extensive should the negative testing be?

it should be as extensive as you and your team feels is worth. the purpose of tests is to let you sleep better. if the microservice is a free service that returns time in a specified time zone built as a pet project to learn new technology - probably nothing will happen if user pass wrong data and service crashes. if that's a flight control system, i would test if passing wrong parameters won't kill hundreds of people

So, in fact you and your team are the only ones who can answer that question

Usually on real systems you use one framework that exposes rest endpoints. It's work to test one of such endpoints to check all the malformed inputs (wrong json, wrong method etc) just to check if the framework's validation is wired correctly and then you test every single endpoint to check validation specific for that endpoint. Having parameterized tests and request builders usually allow adding such tests as one-liners

> A secondary question - are there certain characters that the service should never accept e.g. \?<> for security reasons?

depends. how will you use that data? if its a user password you definitely should accept it - it's a valid password, right? but if it's a phone number that you are going to display as pure html then you should use some white-listing